# Not found error on get url with additive parameters

Tags: laravel

In laravel 6 I need to run control action with url like :

```
http://127.0.0.1/ads/showad?wid=207ce8c0-b153-11eb-b997-4d6d53720d0c&subid=
```

In routes/web.php I have:

```
Route::get('ads/showad', 'DisplayAdController@showad')->name('show_ad');
```

I got not found error
I tried to modify this url definition as :

```
Route::get('ads/showad?wid={wid}&subid={subid?}', 'DisplayAdController@showad')->name('show_ad');
```

and after clearing cache running command :

```
php artisan route:list
```

I see in output :

```
 GET|HEAD  | ads/showad                              | show_ad                 | App\Http\Controllers\DisplayAdController@showad                     
        

| GET|HEAD  | ads/showad?wid={wid}&subid={subid?}     | show_ad                 | App\Http\Controllers\DisplayAdController@showad                        |
```

Anyway I got Not Found error.
How have I to modify url defintion to run url, which must be run from external apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Url/get parameters should not be added to routes. You could set your route to `Route::get('ads/showad/{wid}/{subid?}'...`. Or use your first route `Route::get('ads/showad'...`

Comment: Your first Route is correct, the second one is wrong. Did you run "php artisan serve"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second route is unnecessary.

In your controller you can access to the query parameters like this:

```php
public function showad(Request $request) {
  $request->get('wid');
}
```

you can also use url parameters like this:

```php
Route::get('ads/showad/{wid}/{subid}', 'DisplayAdController@showadById')->name('show_ad_by_id');
```

In this case you need to do this:

```php
public function showadById($wid, $subid) {
}
```